# Deploying Jboss into Azure failing due to script error- ARM Template

Tags: azure, jboss7.x, redhat, azure-rm-template

i am executing arm template provided in this link [ARM to deploy jboss on azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/templates/jboss-eap-standalone-rhel7/), while executing the ARM template, i am getting below error.

```
 {"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please 
 list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage 
 details.","details":[{"code":"Conflict","message":"{\r\n \"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n \"error\": 
 {\r\n \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n \"message\": \"The resource operation completed 
 with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\r\n \"details\": [\r\n {\r\n \"code\": 
 \"VMExtensionProvisioningError\",\r\n \"message\": \"VM has reported a failure when processing 
 extension 'newuserscript'. Error message: \\\"Enable failed: failed to execute command: command 
 terminated with exit status=1\\n[stdout]\\nLoaded plugins: langpacks, product- 
 id\\n\\n[stderr]\\nFailed to execute operation: Access denied\\neap-setup-redhat.sh: line 37: 
 /etc/opt/rh/eap7/wildfly/eap7-standalone.conf: No such file or directory\\neap-setup-redhat.sh: 
 line 38: /etc/opt/rh/eap7/wildfly/eap7-standalone.conf: No such file or directory\\nmv: cannot move 
 ‘/home/vmadmin_2019/dukes/target/dukes.war’ to 
 ‘/opt/rh/eap7/root/usr/share/wildfly/standalone/deployments/dukes.war’: No such file or 
 directory\\neap-setup-redhat.sh: line 47: 
 /opt/rh/eap7/root/usr/share/wildfly/standalone/deployments/dukes.war.dodeploy: No such file or 
 directory\\neap-setup-redhat.sh: line 50: /opt/rh/eap7/root/usr/share/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh: No 
 such file or directory\\nFailed to restart eap7-standalone.service: Unit eap7-standalone.service 
 failed to load: No such file or directory.\\nchown: invalid user: ‘vmadmin_2019.jboss’\\nchown: 
 invalid user: ‘vmadmin_2019.jboss’\\nchown: invalid user: ‘vmadmin_2019.tomcat’\\nchown: invalid 
 user: ‘vmadmin_2019.jboss’\\nchown: invalid user: ‘vmadmin_2019.jboss’\\n\\\".\"\r\n }\r\n ]\r\n 
 }\r\n}"}]}
```

not sure what is causing the error. getting error while deploying dukes.war.

Comment: something is definitely wrong with the template, contact the template author or create an issue on the arm template examples repo

Comment: i have created an issue , but no response..